How to generate an APA style bibliography in latex using biblatex?
I have the babel and biblatex usepackages, \addbibresource{}, \bibliography{} commands but the bibliography isn't generated at the end of the document. I'm using texstudio. The code is as follows:
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
..............….............
\printbibliography
\end{document}


Have you run biber on the file? You need to compile with latex, then run biber and then run latex another one or two times. Also, you don't need the \bibliography command (\addbibresource is sufficent) and you don't need the \DeclareLanguageMapping command any more.  See Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa} hasn't been required for biblatex-apa for years. Any sources that still recommends it is seriously outdated and should be treated with care (and should not be trusted blindly). You don't need both \addbibresource and \bibliography for the same .bib file. Use only one of the two commands. (biblatex prefers \addbibresource.) Note that for \addbibresource the file ending must be included, in \bibliography it must not be included.
